# Logging all uncaught exceptions Eclipse E4

Tags: java-8, eclipse-rcp, logback, e4

I'm logging all my caught exceptions in my database using Logback. Now I need to log all the exceptions that are not caught. How can I log all the exceptions in E4 that are thrown and not handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put a class implementing `org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.IEventLoopAdvisor` in the application context its `eventLoopException` method will be called for each unhandled exception.

The `@PostContextCreate` method of your LifeCycle class is a good place to do this:

```
@PostContextCreate
public void postContextCreate(final IEclipseContext context)
{
  context.set(IEventLoopAdvisor.class, yourEventLoopClass);

  ...
}
```

Note that this is an internal interface but this usage seems to be valid.